# Any disadvantages if I reuse fletches?

Tags: gear, archery

I've had a lot of broken arrows a week ago. I decided to salvage them and carefully removed the fletches along with the other reusable things.

However, now that I have the fletches, I asked myself if it's even a good idea to reuse them!? Are there any disadvantages regarding the arrow behavior (like the second twisting may have influences)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh the amount of arrows I have had to repair. If the fletching is undamaged and you can fully remove the fixing agent, yes, you can reuse them. However, fletchings are rather cheap to buy so for the sake of a possible missed shot due to some damage you might have missed, it is usually advised to buy new ones.

Comment: Does this vary at all by the material of the fletch?

Comment: Yes it does. I suppose I was answering from a recurve point of view, of which they are made of plastic. It would be near enough impossible to reuse a feltching from a wooden arrow as they are generally damaged when they come off.